# Error in running save/restore model functions in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my program I'm saving my model and later restoring it.

I have to run this program several times in a loop with different parameters.

The first iteration runs as expected, the model is saved and restored and works properly, but in the second iteration, the model is trained and saved but while restoring it seems to go to the previous model.

I have kept the directories different for each iteration and therefore the path for the models is different.

The way I'm doing it is as follows:

`1. save_path = self.saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")`

`2. saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/model.ckpt.meta',clear_devices=True)`

`3. saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp/'))`

It gives the error:
`InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [649,1024] rhs shape= [660,1024]`

`InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch`
`between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not`
`altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.`

lhs shape is the shape of one of the variables in the model saved in the first iteration.

I don't see why they mix up and I'm stuck on it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the same session or do you create a new one for each model?

Comment: @de1 the sessions are different.